# Using Windows Authentication from asp.net forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, mvvm, windows-authentication

I have a MVVM Silverlight RIA business application with a small subsection of .net webforms that will be ran on a PDA.. The Silverlight application uses Windows Authentication so that on each page I can call an AuthenticationDomainService to get the logged in user like this...

```
 LoadOperation loadUserOp = authContext.Load(authContext.GetUserQuery());
        loadUserOp.Completed += new EventHandler(loadUserOp_Completed);

   void loadUserOp_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            User user = authContext.Users.First();
            CurrentUserLogin = user.Name;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

I need a way so that I can login via windows authentication in the Codebehind of the asp.net login page for the PDA and then get access to the authContext from inside those asp.net code behind pages.  Thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean that a PDA user types the Username/Password from his/her Windows account?

Comment: Yes... For our Main silverlight project the application uses the Windows login (prompting if you aren't logged in) upon visiting the site.... For the PDA I have designed a small login page that authenticates against Active Directory via LDAP and this article... (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2218/Authenticating-Active-Directory-user-in-ASP-NET) But now I need a way to authenticate the user on each page and call upon the called upon user to make changes to the database.

Comment: Codebehind runs on the IIS Server, the authContext runs on the client. There is no shared code. Why do you need access to the client's auth context? You should use HttpContext.Current.User